# Getting null data for left join on same table twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have some tables like this:

Employee:

```
EmployeeId      Name        DeptId
----------------------------------
100             John        100
101             Kery        100
102             Tiny        100
```

Teams:

```
TeamId      TeamLeaderId    TeamName
------------------------------------------
1           100             Finance-2021
```

TeamMember:

```
TeamMemberId    TeamId      EmployeeId
----------------------------------------
1               1           101
```

I am trying to get list of employees with info regarding who they are : `Team Member or Team Leader or Individual`.

Current output:

```
TeamId      TeamName        EmployeeIdentity    EmployeeId    EmployeeName
------------------------------------------------------------------
null        null            Team Leader         100             John
1           Finance-2021    Team Member         101             Kery
```

Expected output:

```
TeamId      TeamName        EmployeeIdentity    EmployeeId      EmployeeName
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Finance-2021    Team Leader         100             John
1           Finance-2021    Team Member         101             Kery
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO #tempMembers (ID)
    (SELECT EmployeeId 
     FROM TeamMembers
     WHERE TeamId IN (1) AND IsDeleted = 0
     UNION   
     SELECT TeamLeaderId 
     FROM TEAMS
     WHERE TeamId IN (1))

SELECT
    t.TeamId as 'TeamId',
    t.TeamName as 'TeamName',
    CASE 
        WHEN tm.EmployeeId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Team Member'
        WHEN t1.TeamLeaderId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Team Leader'
        ELSE 'Individual'
    END AS 'EmployeeIdentity',
    e.EmployeeId as 'EmployeeId',
    e.EmployeeName as 'EmployeeName',
FROM
    Employee AS e
LEFT JOIN
    TeamMember tm ON tm.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND tm.IsDeleted = 0
LEFT JOIN
    Teams t ON t.TeamId = tm.TeamId
LEFT JOIN
    Teams t1 ON t1.TeamLeaderId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE
    e.IsDeleted = 0 
    AND e.EmployeeId IN (SELECT * FROM #tempMembers)
```

Only issue here is that I am getting `TeamId and TeamName` as blank for "Team Leader" data as shown below:

Current output:

```
TeamId      TeamName        EmployeeIdentity    EmployeeId      EmployeeName
null        null            Team Leader         100             John
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach does not need a temp table and uses the nulls from the left join to determine whether a member is a `Team Member`, `Team Leader` or `Individual`.

The where condition applies the filter from your initial union in the temp table.

I've also included a  db-fiddle below to demonstrate.

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
       WHEN tl.TeamLeaderId IS NOT NULL THEN tl.TeamId
       WHEN tmt.TeamId IS NOT NULL THEN tmt.TeamId
       ELSE NULL
    END as TeamId,
    CASE
       WHEN tl.TeamLeaderId IS NOT NULL THEN tl.TeamName
       WHEN tmt.TeamName IS NOT NULL THEN tmt.TeamName
       ELSE NULL
    END as TeamName,
    CASE
        WHEN tl.TeamLeaderId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Team Leader'
        WHEN tm.EmployeeId IS NOT NULL THEN 'Team Member'
        ELSE 'Individual'
    END as EmployeeIdentity,
    e.EmployeeId,
    e.Name as EmployeeName
FROM
    Employee e
LEFT JOIN
    Teams tl ON e.EmployeeId = tl.TeamLeaderId AND tl.isDeleted=0
LEFT JOIN
    TeamMember tm ON e.EmployeeId = tm.EmployeeId AND tm.isDeleted=0
LEFT JOIN
    Teams tmt ON tm.TeamId = tmt.TeamId AND tmt.isDeleted=0
WHERE 
    tl.TeamId = 1 OR tmt.TeamId=1
```

| TeamId | TeamName | EmployeeIdentity | EmployeeId | EmployeeName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Finance-2021 | Team Leader | 100 | John |
| 1 | Finance-2021 | Team Member | 101 | Kery |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rmPCRXeXKvoKCXmuYv2zw5/1) or [SQL Server Db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3cbb2cd852f7088b8e00040b059828d)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are one way:

```
select 
    t.teamid, t.teamName, 'Team Member' as EmployeeIdentity  ,    
    e.employeeid , e.emplyeename 
from
    Employee e 
join 
    TeamMember tm on tm.employeeid = e.employeeid 
join 
    teams t on tm.TeamId = t.TeamId
union all 
select 
    t.teamid, t.teamName, 'Team Leader' as EmployeeIdentity, 
    e.employeeid , e.emplyeename  
from 
    employees e 
join 
    Teams t on t.teamleaderid = e.employeeid
```

or even better:

```
select 
    t.teamid, t.teamName, EmployeeIdentity, e.employeeid, e.emplyeename 
from 
    Employee e 
join
    (select 
         TeamId, Employeeid, 'Team Member' as EmployeeIdentity 
     from TeamMember 
     union all 
     select teamid, TeamLeaderId, 'Team Leader' as EmployeeIdentity 
     from team) as tm on tm.employeeid = e.employeeid 
join 
    teams t on tm.TeamId = t.TeamId
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you are getting teamid and teamname from t, when in the leader case it comes from t1. Try this:

```
Case When t.TeamId is null then t1.TeamId else t.TeamId end as 'TeamId',
Case When t.TeamName is null then t1.TeamName else t.TeamId end as 'TeamName',
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can select both the team leader and the team members in an `APPLY`, then join `Employee` on that. No self-joins or temp tables are necessary**

```sql
SELECT
  t.TeamId,
  t.TeamName,
  m.EmployeeIdentity,
  e.EmployeeId,
  e.Name AS EmployeeName
FROM Teams t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      t.TeamLeaderId AS EmployeeId,
      'Team Leader' AS EmployeeIdentity
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      tm.EmployeeId,
      'Team Member'
    FROM TeamMember tm
    WHERE tm.TeamId = t.TeamId
) m
JOIN Employee e ON e.EmployeeId = m.EmployeeId
  AND e.IsDeleted = 0
WHERE t.TeamId = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5623eb7e527ce2ebc962ba957ef7f1c)